# Why can’t iPhone 13 Pro do macro video?

Tags: iphone, video, camera

The iPhone 13 Pro has an amazing macro photography feature. When you switch to video mode, it doesn’t work.  Why not?

Screen recording from camera:

https://youtube.com/shorts/2EvkAfJ6L6A?feature=share

Comment: What does "not work" mean? Is the 0.5 lense not available for selection in video mode, can you not select it, or anything else?

Comment: By “not work”, I mean the same very short distance from the camera cannot be brought to focus in video mode as in photo mode

Comment: Macro video recording is a feature of the iPhone 13 Pro - https://www.apple.com/iphone-13-pro/specs/ perhaps your scene isn’t lit well enough to have it focus down? We would likely need to look over your shoulder and compare with same and previous phone to assist, though.

Comment: Added screen recording to demo what I mean

Comment: Scene is daylight, well lit etc. I can capture the camera app showing an in focus “video” of the macro shot in photo mode. But I can’t record a video file at the same focal length. It’s weird.